# How to display HTML stored in a database from an ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-encode

I have HTML code edited by FCKEditor stored in a database and would like to display (well render) it onto a view. So, for instance, something stored as:

```
&lt;&gt;pre&lt;&gt;This is some sample text&lt;&gt;pre&lt;/&gt
```

Will be displayed to the user as:

```
This is some sample text
```

(With the appropriate style for pre-formatted-text)

The view already has the required string to display from `ViewData`, I'm just not sure what the best way to show it to the user is.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yourEncodedHtmlFromYouDatabase) %>
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx).

Comment: this doesn't work for Razor, for Razor use @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.yourhtmlvalue))

Comment: Checking the date of my answer .. it was PRE Razor :P

Comment: Thanks for bringing the date to my attention Pure, I have quoted just for somebody's info, its true Razor was not in existence when u posted your answer.

Answer (score 52):

The answer provided by Pure.Krome is flawless for MVC2, but consider Razor syntax:

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.yourEncodedHtmlFromYourDatabase))
```

Alternatively,

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.yourEncodedHtmlFromYourDatabase))
```

Comment: How can I make it so to be a link text

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `@Html.Raw(str)`.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw) for more information.

> Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.
>
> This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which renders unencoded HTML.