# How to Insert Line Break using LabelFor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, line-breaks

I have in my Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Check to enter <break> the Quantity of items")]
public bool IsLimitedQuantity { get; set; }
```

and I am using

```
@Html.LabelFor(shop => shop.IsLimitedQuantity)
```

in my view.

Please suggest how I can fix this, because the label is just showing <break> as it is, instead of breaking to a new line.

Comment: <br/> is being rendered as it is...how to give line break...please help !!!

Comment: If this is because the label is display too side, then you should be using CSS to fix this, not HTML.

Answer (score 8):

You could write a custom `LabelFor` helper which doesn't HTML encode the text as does the standard `LabelFor` helper:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString UnencodedLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var text = (metadata.DisplayName ?? (metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last<string>()));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml = text;
        return new HtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and then use this custom helper in the view:

```
@Html.UnencodedLabelFor(x => x.IsLimitedQuantity)
```

Now the HTML tags in the display name will be rendered without encoding:

```
[Display(Name = "Check to enter <br/> the Quantity of items")]
public bool IsLimitedQuantity { get; set; }
```

Comment: Totally valid solution (and +1 for it), but allowing DSL/markup in metadata makes me feel barfy.

Comment: Perfect :) and I were to put it in Resources instead of metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Using Html decode may help. MVC for security reasons encode all the values.

[How to display HTML stored in a database from an ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300424/how-do-i-display-html-stored-in-a-database-from-an-asp-net-mvc-view)

Comment: so you mean something like this? @Server.HtmlDecode(Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Val1).ToHtmlString())

Comment: even you can try @Darin solution as well