# Inserting line breaks in DisplayName attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In my ViewModel there is a property that needs a 2 line label but when I place a `<br />` in the `DisplayName` attribute the HTML code is printed to the page instead of being interpreted as a line break. Is there a way to get a `DisplayName` to have a line break in it?

View:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GrossGallons)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

ViewModel:

```
    [DisplayName("Gross Gallons <br /> (Max: 6,000)")]
    public decimal GrossGallons { get; set; }
```

Output trying to get:

```
Gross Gallons
(Max: 6,000)
```

Comment: Are you using `@Html.EditorFor(...)`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `@Html.EditorFor()` to display the input option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Insert Line Break using LabelFor in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478454/how-to-insert-line-break-using-labelfor-in-mvc)

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete - take a look at Darins answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478454/how-to-insert-line-break-using-labelfor-in-mvc.  Basically, without resorting to hacks, you should make your own label creating Html helper so that you can render out the Html unencoded.  I would simply use this everywhere in place of the standard Html.LabelFor so you don't have to track which labels have html and which ones don't

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this - use `\n` instead of `<br />`, and use CSS to make it work.

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Gross Gallons\n(Max: 6,000)")]
public decimal GrossGallons { get; set; }
```

CSS:

```
label { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

I would recommend making the CSS selector as specific as possible, so as not to catch other labels (in case you're using labels by hand elsewhere, where your source code may contain whitespace).  For example, in bootstrap I would've applied this to `label.control-label`.

You could also attach a more specific style to that label only, and style only that class.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GrossGallons, new { @class = "multiline-label" })
```

Comment: That was easy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options.

1) You could use @Html.Raw().  You can replace the string I have entered with a reference to a string.

```
@Html.Raw("Gross Gallons <br /> (Max: 6,000)");
```

1a) If you need to set it in the DisplayName attribute, then you might try using Html.Raw() but accessing the value through reflection. (Note: I haven't tried this, so don't know if it is possible)

2) You could use css styling to force the line to wrap where you want it to.

3) You could create a custom extension method or custom attribute to do this for you.

Comment: 1: That would defeat the purpose of using the `@Html.LabelFor`.

2: I really don't think using a CSS hack would be either efficient or proper to do.

3: I had thought about a custom extension but I was hoping there might be a simpler MVC solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Html.Raw(), I think this is the most simple way.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of using the `@Html.LabelFor`.

Comment: @Html.LabelFor is not @Html.Raw()

Comment: @Html.LabelFor is <label for=""></label>

Comment: I know the difference between the too HTML helpers. In my example I use the `@Html.LabelFor()` because I want the code to generate the `<label />` tag. Moving to use the `@Html.Raw` defeats the entire reason of using `@Html.LabelFor()` in the first place. I am not even sure you could pass in the model and get the `DisaplyName` attribute to be parsed by the `@Html.Raw` helper.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you could use `EditorTemplates` and create a `_layout.cshtml` that all your Templates use. Then use this to pull/display the `DisplayName`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">
        @Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName())
    </label>
    @RenderBody()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)
</div>
```

The serious drawback to this is you would have to create EditorTemplates for each of your types like this sample `string.cshtml` template:

```
@model string
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @class="form-control" })
```

A little off-topic but going this route allows me to encapsulate wrapping HTML around my form elements, so my forms in the views end up really simple like this:

```
<fieldset>
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address1)
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address2)
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why are you placing the label and validation message into the layout page instead of just right in the page where all the other form markup is at?

Comment: Because I only have to do it there once versus every time everywhere else. @Html.EditorFor() takes care of that for me.

Comment: Again, its not pretty. :-) I dont like the built in EditorFor templates so I usually end up writing my own for all the types anyway. Therefore its not a problem for me, however if you are fine with the built in, well then a lot of extra work....

Comment: But placing that in the layout template would screw up pages not displaying the form data or any form data that is using a model that does not have the `DisplayPropery` attribute, right?

Comment: Yes and No, if you use EditorFor it would drop in the Layout stuff. I only use EditorFor inside a standard form.

`GetDisplayName()` returns `PropertyName` if the `DisplayName` attribute is not used.

Answer (score 0):

If use `LabelFor()`, another "possible" solution is to implement your own using the [original source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LabelExtensions.cs) as a guide.

Replace

```
tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
```

with

```
tag.InnerHtml = resolvedLabelText;
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work with `EditorFor` though.