# <br> tag in @Html.LabelFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to split lable into two lines. But if put 
 in the  `@Html.LabelFor` it is not working is there any alternative options?

### controller

```
meetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel = meetingQuestionses[0].question_text 
                           + "/" + meetingQuestionses[0].question_text_en;
```

### view

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, 
   Model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, new { @class = "control-label mandatory" })
```

Comment: are you searching [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478454/how-to-insert-line-break-using-labelfor-in-mvc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom HtmlHelper.

Inherit `IHtmlString` and use `TagBuilder` to create one.

Then you can use it with `@Html.CustomLabelFor(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a regular label

```
<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel)"
  class="control-label mandatory">
    Text above
    Text below
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

so that the html will render you will need to use html.raw.  try changing it to this

```
<label class="control-label mandatory">@Html.Raw(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to put break within label? After 1st, 2nd, 3rd, n-th word?

IMHO, it's better to increase the height of label and let HTML render it on it's own.

In your css set:

```
.control-label{
    height: 60px;  /* or change accordingly */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, 
   Model.AbstractTitleInEnglishLabel, new { @class = "control-label mandatory" }).ToString()))