# @Html.LabelFor with an <a> tag inside it

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This should be a fairly simple question, all I want to do is use @Html.LabelFor within a razor view.  One of my labels is different, it has an <a> tag in it.  the problem is when I use LabelFor, it encodes the html as & lt;.  I've tried a lot of different approaches to making this happen but none of them are working.  Here's the code.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question, new { @for = "Question" })
```

what should get outputted:

```
<label for="question"><a href=\"mailto:support@testdomain.com">support@testdomain.com</a></label>
```

what does get outputted:

```
&lt;label for="question"&gt;&lt;a href=\"mailto:support@testdomain.com"&gt;support@testdomain.com&lt;/a&gt;</label>
```

(my < have been replaced with & lt ; without the spaces, thus the code shows on the page instead of rendering as a link)

how can I make it output what it should?

note, model.Question is set to  <a href="mailto:support@testdomain.com">support@testdomain.com</a>

Comment: I have tried using different overloads of html.labelfor, including passing in a string by itself.  this also get's encoded.  I've even tried html.raw.  it also comes back encoded.

Comment: How did you use Html.Raw? Hint: It will have been encoded into the database.

Comment: Does not seem to make sense. A `<label>` element is an accessibility control - when you click on it, focus is set to the associated control. You wanting to open the email editor, so it should not be a label.

Comment: Previous answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063356/br-tag-in-html-labelfor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594446/nesting-a-element-inside-html-labelfor

Comment: I was like most people in asking why an `<a>` tag in a `<label>`. I think, the above use is acceptable [based on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). The `<a>` tag is like a a [phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/content-models.html#phrasing-content) in this case. See also this [SO item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233447/what-is-the-difference-between-phrasing-content-and-flow-content). Although I prefer not to have a link in my `<label>` particularly if I am using the `for` attribute with an input field.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the design and just not put a link in the label, that's out of scope from my part.  An additional complication is that this particular label only shows as a link if the user is browsing the site in a particular language.  otherwise, it should show as regular text.  so I can't just output the regular label and then add a mailto link to the markup because it'd show in every language.  I also can't check the language on the view and render selectively only for this particular language, that's not how the site is configured.

Comment: rism, i was using 
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question, Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.Question)).ToString(), new { @for = "Question" })

still doesn't work, with htmldecode or html.raw or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fighting the Razor system since it encodes by default. That's the beauty of using Razor. Many of the tag classes including `Label`will ultimately render themselves by calling `TagBuilderExtensions.ToMvcHtmlString`

```
internal static class TagBuilderExtensions
  {
    internal static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this TagBuilder tagBuilder, TagRenderMode renderMode)
    {
      return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(renderMode));
    }
  }
```

[MvcHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again. So you can't do what you're trying to do via `LabelFor`. Razor is in fact specifically ensuring that you can't.

But since your malto: is not really a label anyway you can just:

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.MyField)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want your label to contain the full HTML? I think it would be a better approach to store email address, and in your view you could do:

```
 <a href="mailto:@Model.Email">@Model.Email</a>
```

To get the expected result.

**EDIT**

IMO by encoding things in label is just going to make your work more complicated as labels are not meant to hold formatted HTML or feature or anything like that, merely a caption to display. Example usage:

Model code:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

In view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress): 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)

<!-- OR (no label element just the label text)-->

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress): 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
```

Then can be combined in any way:

```
[Display(Name = "Send Email")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

And

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress): <a href="mailto:@Model.EmailAddress">@Model.Email</a>
```

In runtime will be:

**Send Email:** [abc@server.com](http://mailto:abc@server.com)

Comment: --ignore this comment--

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. You are creating problem for yourself by using label which is containing html string or even feature. Label was supposed to be used for displaying the name (or very short description) of the property, see updated answer...