# Load HTML into page, acquired as text at first

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was working in ASP and (for testing purposes) I was reading HTML from text file and load it into the page, and the design was looking fine (doesn't matter whether I put it as returned value from function, or with some kind of controls). 
But I had to move the project to ASP-MVC, so now I am doing the same thing: get the HTML from the file, in the Controller of the certain View I set the string value (of the HTML) to a ViewBag and then the ViewBag in the .cshtml file - but I get it as text. All of the HTML that is from the file is shown just as text, instead of read from the browser as HTML.

the controller:

```
public ActionResult Products()
        {
            string asd = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/Content/pagesHTML/sample_page.html");
            ViewBag.Gaga = asd;

            return View();
        }
```

and the .cshtml file:

```
<div id="parent">
     @ViewBag.Gaga
    </div>
```

Any ideas why I get the HTML just as plain text, instead of being read from the browser as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@ViewBag.Gaga))
```

From this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300424/how-do-i-display-html-stored-in-a-database-from-an-asp-net-mvc-view).

Also found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756464/how-do-i-render-html-from-the-viewbag-using-mvc3-razor) with a simpler syntax.